# starting with symfony 2 (app_dev.php works, app.php 404's)

Tags: symfony

I was following the tutorials for symfony, and have hit a road block.

my setup is the current version of xampp (running on windows), so my apache and php are relatively up to date.

following their "quick tour" here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

everything worked great in the development environment. following the guides a little further however, i started creating my own test bundle via the guide here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html

and can't get it to work properly on the production environment. (it works fine in the dev environment, just like the pre-installed demos did.

i have tried clearing the cache via the php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug command, however that did not help (and also seems to be the only suggestion that pops up upon searching.

when viewing the routes, i can see that my "/hello/{name}" route is showing up fine on the list of routes.

my app/config/routing.yml has:

```
acme_hello:
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

as it should, and then  my src/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml has

```
hello:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index }
```

does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem might be? (i have also tried converting the out of the box demo to a production route, by copying the route info from the routing_dev.yml file and reassigning the bundle in the appkernel.php file, but that had the same problem)

---edit---

per request, here is my appkernel.php file

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new Acme\HelloBundle\AcmeHelloBundle(),
            new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

---2nd edit---

i found the problem. i thought it was strange that nothing was showing up in the prod log, so i thought maybe something was redirecting me, causing me to miss the app.php file entirely.

it turns out, this was the problem. i emptied the contents of the .htaccess file that was in the web folder (the one that symfony came preconfigured with) and then everything magically started working.

Comment: What says the app/logs/prod.log if you call your productive page?

Comment: for whatever reason, no entries are getting created in the prod.log file. there were a few entries about a missing gif file with yesterday's date, but nothing logged today.

Comment: And what says the apache error.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem. i thought it was strange that nothing was showing up in the prod log, so i thought maybe something was redirecting me, causing me to miss the app.php file entirely.

it turns out, this was the problem. i emptied the contents of the .htaccess file that was in the web folder (the one that symfony came preconfigured with) and then everything magically started working.

Answer (score 11):

I also had the same problem. I share how I solved it (Strange but it works).

In file web/app.php change:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

by

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true); // Enable debug mode
```

Then load the page in the browser (in app environment) and change the file again disabling debug:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

Try loading the page in the browser again. It should work properly.

Best regards,

Answer (score 6):

If you are like me, just want to get the sample application from the tutorial to run in Apache, then this may help you.
I ran into the same problem with version 2.5 just now, and finally found the answer here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

```
The demo routes in our application are only available in the dev environment. 
Therefore, if you try to access the .../app.php/... URL, you'll get a 404 error.
```

The easiest way to get it to work is to use app_dev.php instead of app.php.

Just edit .htaccess and change all occurrences of app.php to app_dev.php, like this:

Line 6:

```
DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
```

Line 41:

```
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks man. this is so bad that there is no one mentioning about this. even tutorials or anything else.

Comment: Be aware that this is a quite "quick and dirty" solution! It will enable the "dev" mode generally and therefore should never be used in production! Instead, you will have to find and solve the real cause of the problem to make sure everything works as it is intended.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to warm up your cache for the prod environment? You can do this by running the following command:

```
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

Also you could check your routes by running

```
php app/console router:debug
```

If you want to get specific information on a route you can do `php app/console router:debug yourRouteName`. But maybe thats what you meant with "viewing the routes".

Another hint has to do with [Assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html).
Usually if you move your app from dev to prod environment you have to run the following commands:

```
php app/console assets:install web_directory
php app/console assetic:dump web_directory
```

Assetic:dump physically genereates your assets, like css stylesheets or javascript files. Something to read about this in detail is [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment)

Perhaps you could edit your post and post your AppKernel.php? Maybe the bundle isn't activated there?

Comment: the php app/console router:debug is the command that i had used prior to view my routes. after i saw your post, i got the detailed view for the /hello/{name} route, but nothing jumped out as looking wrong when i viewed it.

i hadn't previously done the warm up, but tried that, and the install/dump commands. still no luck.

Comment: Hmm...your AppKernel.php looks normal to me. Did you try the other commands like cache:warmup etc.?

Comment: yup, i tried that.

i also tried php app/console router:debug -e=prod, so i could just see the routes for the production environment, and both my /hello/{name} and my /demo/hello/{name} show up there.

do you think it could be because all of my symfony stuff is in a symfony folder as opposed to having it all dumped into the root of my htdocs folder? (so to get to app.php, its htdocs/symfony/web/app.php instead of htdocs/web/app.php)

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was caused by cache. After clearing the cache, the new route worked fine on prod environmment (app.php), no 404's.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I fixed the issue by first clearing the cache from the command line using the following command:
**php app/console cache:clear --env=prod**
After this, I removed the cache folder itself from the app directory (*as I couldn't still access my bundle but only the default Symfony homepage*) and then refreshed the browser and the error was gone. 
Hope this helps.