# Symfony2 installation error

Tags: php, symfony

I just create new project with symfony2 in wamp server (local pc)

When I try to run this url : `http://localhost/symfony/web/`

I am getting following error.

Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "404 Not Found".
Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused

If any one has idea that why this is coming ......... then please help me. I am new in symfony2, and its frustrating for me

Answer (score 3):

If you extract the zip in localhost and did nothing with it yet, then try

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/
```

Comment: Writing path on routing.yml instead of routing_dev.yml did the trick for me. I didn't need to do anything else. Though I find some source that you might need incase anything goes wrong.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997543/why-is-my-symfony2-install-404ing-when-i-access-app-php

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243746/starting-with-symfony-2-app-dev-php-works-app-php-404s

Comment: Note: you might want to use the app_dev.php while coding and testing, cause it immediately shows you the changes made like in css or js. But with app.php browser uses the 'cache' more often. app.php is basically needed when you put it on live server for production use.

Answer (score 0):

By default your server is looking for index.(html|php). Symfony2's default file is not called index.php but app.php, I think that's your problem. With xampp I had no issues with a default symfony2 installation, haven't tried it with wamp yet (I usually work on linux).

What I recommend is to have a vhost that's pointing to your web folder.

- http://cesaric.com/?p=255
- http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

There is by default a .htaccess in your web folder containing the following line `RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]` make sure this is working.

Answer (score 0):

By default there is only one router predefined in `AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController`

and it is: `/app/example`

Try: `http://localhost/symfony/web/app/example`

or `http://localhost/symfony/app/example` if you set up front controller